# target _blank funny behaviour

Tags: html, anchor

I'm having a real problem with target _blank. The website is this: `http://www.l2herbal.com/` When I placed a link with target _blank in the menu ('Forum') if the user clicks on it, it opens in a new tab BUT the problem is that `http://www.l2herbal.com/forum` remains in the old address bar. I've checked all the js but found nothing.

Chrome, Mozilla, IE acting the same.

Comment: That's the uh....point of target _blank

Comment: well, that's the point...thanks for the -1 by the way.

Comment: It's no good to point to your live website, which will be fixed once the answer has been given. You should reproduce a minimal test-case so this question and its answers can benefit future visitors.

Comment: @CosminSerbanescu Don't thank me ;), I wouldn't -1 for something which is a misunderstanding, what is it that you're trying to accomplish? Do you just want a link to redirect in the same window?

Comment: This website requires that you put the code as well into your question. It's not clear what you're asking about when this website goes down. Also try to turn your individual problem into a general one. Stackoverflow is not a support forum for individual problems but just to answer programming questions for a more general audience.

Comment: @CosminSerbanescu check JS console after navigating to forum. There is an error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /forum`

Comment: @hakre Yes it is. This is a place to ask about specific problems. General ones are generally off-topic.

Comment: All I needed is to have forum open up in a new tab, now it opens but in the old address bar there's website.com/forum and if I click on something else it goes to website.com/forum#anyotherlink which is not the regular behaviour, right? Sorry for the links to the actual website - trust me I wasn't ooking for backlinks or anything related to seo

Comment: Read my comment, I was less concerned about some SEO sheme, but now as you name it, you have admitted to have it in mind :) - If you've got questions about how linking works, what in all those references out there is not clear to you? If you would make that an actual question, I'd say it should be easy to answer instead of commenting / discussing around the hot pudding.

Comment: @CosminSerbanescu I can't duplicate your behaviour. Click on "Forum" and the forum opens in a new tab, but in the old tab it still has the old URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with this script: http://www.l2herbal.com/js/scrollTo.min.js

Here is a code that changes window URL:

```
window.location.hash = d
```

You applied it to all menu links in http://www.l2herbal.com/js/main.js:

```
$('#nav-boxes a, .logo a, #nav a, #navmobile ul a').scrollTo({ duration: 'slow' });
```

Change `#nav-boxes a` selector to exclude forum url.

Comment: I think this is the solution. However my js skills require some extra time to modify this selector :)

Comment: @CosminSerbanescu `$('#nav-boxes a[href]:not([href="./forum"])')`

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting html from your site I did found `href="/forum"`

Place a dot(.) before `/forum` in `href` to indicate forum in current(root) directory

Use

```
<a style="width: 16.6667%;" class="menu-5" href="./forum" target="_blank">

                        <div></div><span>Forum</span></a>
```

Instead of

```
<a style="width: 16.6667%;" class="menu-5" href="/forum" target="_new">

                        <div></div><span>Forum</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but it didn't work

Comment: Will you try it, `href="./forum/"`